# How to render the same view for all actions in the same controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to render the same view in the controller for all my actions. For instance, I have:

```
class FooController 
  def action1
    #action1 code
  end

  # [...]

  def actionN
    #actionN code
  end 

end
```

And then I want that all actions render `generic_page.html`.

I tried with:

```
...
after_filter :render_generic

...
private 
  def render_generic
    render 'generic_page'
  end
```

But `render` method is being called before `after_filter` and I'm getting a `Template Missing` error because it isn't rendering the correct template. Does anyone know a simple solution for that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just be explicit:

```
def action1
  #action1 code
  render_generic
end

def actionN
  #actionN code
  render_generic
end

private
  def render_generic
    render 'generic_page'
  end
```

Answer (score 6):

using [rescue_from](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from)

```
    class FooController
      rescue_from ActionView::MissingTemplate do
        render 'generic_page'
      end

    end
```